# Regular expression to match all words except those containing a certain pattern

Tags: regex, word-list

Suppose I have two lists of words and I have to match **all** words in the **first list** but **none** in the **second list**. Now suppose all the words in the second list (those that are **not** to be matched) contain specific pattern: *character1* followed by *character2* then *character2* and *character1* again. For example, it contains such words as "abba", "otto", "trillion", "unfitting", etc.

I could easily match this pattern by using regex expression `(\w)(\w)\2\1`. And to match all the words in the second list I could use `\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1\w*`. But how do I match all words EXCEPT those containing this pattern?

One of the things I tried is `(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1\w*)`, but, for some reason it also matches the transition between first and second characters in the second list. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

Comment: `\b(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1)\w+` can do the job since the word boundary ensures that you test a word from the begining.

Comment: @Casimir This did the job! Thank you!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Your comment seems like a good and useful answer, and worth posting as one (at least so it seems to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zeron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492466/zeron) gets a working solution from [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)

> `\b(?!\w*(\w)(\w)\2\1)\w+` can do the job since the word boundary ensures that you test a word from the begining. –  Casimir et Hippolyte Jan 25 at 19:10